# Can not get email address by Facebook login (javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook javascript to handle function login by Facebook.
Before, i can use it, and Facebook send for my server user's info:

localhost

```
v2.2
id:
first_name:
last_name:
email:
token:
```

v2.5 - But, now i only get:

```
id:
first_name:
last_name:
token:
```

Don't have email?
what's problem at here? and how i can fix it.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It is called "Declarative Fields" and came with v2.4 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

You now have to specify the fields you want to get in the API call, or you just get some basic ones.